# Kafka Connect transforming JSON string to actual JSON

Tags: json, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to transform JSON values that are stored as strings into actual JSON structures using Kafka Connect.

I tried looking for such a transformation but couldn't find one. As an example, this could be the source:

```
{
  "UserID":2105058535,
  "DocumentID":2105058535,
  "RandomJSON":"{\"Tags\":[{\"TagID\":1,\"TagName\":\"Java\"},{\"TagID\":2,\"TagName\":\"Kafka\"}]}"
}
```

And this is my goal:

```
{
  "UserID":2105058535,
  "DocumentID":2105058535,
  "RandomJSON":{
    "Tags":[
      {
        "TagID":1,
        "TagName":"Java"
      },
      {
        "TagID":2,
        "TagName":"Kafka"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make these transformations for Elasticsearch sink connector if it makes a difference.

I know I can use Logstash together with JSON filter in order to do this, but I'd like to know whether there's a way to do it using just Kafka Connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like this would be a [Single Message Transform](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms) (thus  applicable to any connector, not just ES), but there aren't any out of the box doing what you describe. The API is [documented here](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html).

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! I'll just have to implement this myself then. :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be easy :| If I understand right, if I want this dynamic, I somehow have to parse that JSON, generate Avro schema for it and then put it as a new field?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but in reverse. I had the data in Json and I needed to convert some of it into a Json string representation to store it in Cassandra using the Cassandra Sink. I ended up **creating a Kafka stream app** that **reads from the topic and then output the Json object to another topic** that is read by the connector.

topic document <- read by your kafka stream with a call to mapValues or create a Jackson POJO that serializes as you want, and then write value to -> topic document.elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

You can use FromJson converter.
Please check this link for more details
https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-json-schema/transformations/examples/FromJson.inline.html